# turn a select option to an input text and save the data upon form submission with j query

Tags: java, jquery

i have this code:

```
<label>something</label>
<select><option>1</option></select>
```

i need to turn the option tag into an input field, then save the data upon the submission of the form.

Comment: Your select input needs a "name" attribute in order to be able to send its data to the server. Also, what's the trigger for changing the select to an input, user click / page load?

Comment: why are you changing the select option to input text, you can directly place input, if you still need this to be done, explain its need we will work on it.

Comment: You should definitely elaborate more on your question, especially what you want to achieve (in terms of usage), what you did try etc. Just throwing requests at us like this won't make many people to be willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should elaborate more on your question.

You cannot replace an option element with an input one. You can replace the whole select with an input which has the value of the select element.

What I assume you want, is an "other" option in your select that triggers free-from input by the user.

see http://jsfiddle.net/TfAy8/5/

For usability considerations you will need a mechanism for reverting to the original select element.